# Conservation of angular momentum of two disks rotating on top of each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

A disk of radius $R_A$ and mass $M_A$ is rotating around its central axis with angular velocity $\omega_0$. We slowly put another disk of radius $R_B<R_A$ and mass $M_B$ such that the distance between the two centers is $d_0$. After the two disks start rotating with the same angular velocity the distance between the centers of the two disks becomes $d$. Using the conservation of angular momentum, find the final angular velocity of the two disks.

My attempt:

the initial angular momentum of disk A is

$L_i=\frac{1}{2}M_A R_A^2\omega_0$

The final angular momentum of the two disks is

$L_f=\omega_f(\frac{1}{2}M_A R_A^2 + M_B(d^2+\frac{1}{2}R_B^2))$

Therefore the final angular velocity is

$\omega_f=\omega_0 \frac{M_AR_A^2}{M_B(2d^2+R_B^2)}$

However, this means that the final angular velocity does not depend on the initial distance between the two centers, and I cannot seem to understand why.

Is there something wrong with the physics? Or is it just my understanding of the result that is wrong?

Thank you in advance!